Navbar from bootstrap(5.3) opens up but does not close when i import bootstrap into component(Angular 17)
As in title the navbar do not close when i import bootstrap into component.
import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap';

It is basic navbar from bootstrap documentation.
<div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">   <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="staticBackdropLabel">Modal title</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Understood</button>
      </div>
    </div>

When i try to open the modal from the bootstrap api with this code it works fine but then the navbar does not close.
const element = document.getElementById('staticBackdrop') as HTMLElement;
const myModal = new Modal(element);
myModal.show();

When i delete above code navbar opens up and closes as expected. I did npm install bootstrap@5.3.3 and placed dependencies into angular.json like so
...
"styles": [
 "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
 "node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css",
 "src/styles.css"
],
"scripts": [
 "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
]
...

Any ideas?
I tried importing dependencies into index.html with cdn and tried to use different imports
import { Modal } from 'bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap';

